# how to get the id of the last div, appended with ajax, with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

i have a div with an id by default, then i append some more divs there with a ajax call.

How do i get those id;s with jquery?

for example:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="0" class="take">test</div>  <!-- this one is here by default -->

    <!-- added by ajax -->
    <div id="1" class="take">test</div>
    <div id="2" class="take">test</div>
    <!-- end added by ajax -->

    <!-- added by another ajax request -->
    <div id="3" class="take">test</div>
    <div id="4" class="take">test</div>
    <!-- end added by ajax -->

</div>
```

if i do:

```
alert($("div.take:last").attr('id');)
```

i will only get `0`. looks like i need to use something like `.live`... This might be very simple and i just don't see it.

any ideas?

thanks

edit: if a add some divs with a request then i add some more i still get `0`

Comment: show us where you call your alert relative to your ajax callback

Comment: maybe this is problems with browser or maybe new divs don't have class `take`, but in all normal browsers such a think work perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the code working that includes adding new `<div>`s using jQuery.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/pAgHG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In the callback of your ajax request you can properly get the correct last div. You cannot do it before the ajax request has completed, otherwise that statement will return the last div found before DOM update

Comment: i agree, however, this is not the case. I am interested only in the existing divs. But you made a good point, i didn't specified that in my question

Answer (score 1):

I agree with fabrizio... you said that your ajax request is appending the div's into DOM. So it might be the case that you are calling

```
alert($("div.take:last").attr('id'););
```

before the request is actually completed. Call the above thing in a callback function (success).

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

ps: is your HTML in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is working fine.. [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/freelancerid/92jFx/).

Try this:

```
// after ajax call..
var last = $('.take').length - 1 ;
alert($(".take").eq(last).attr('id'));
```

Comment: in fiddle you don't add any divs with ajax

Comment: I have updated the solution.. please let me know if it works for you :)